# relative adverb, where

Tags: relative-adverbs

I am wondering if these sentences are correct grammatically when I write the relative adverb, ‘where’

1. I go to the north. The hills are toward the north.
   = I go to the north where the hills are.
2. This is the report. I referred to this report.
   = This is the report where I referred.
3. This is the office. I went to the office.
   = This is the office where I went.

Comment: 1. and 3. are fine, but not 2, which requires "that" or "which", as in _This is the report that/which I referred to_.

Comment: I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This might be considered a duplicate question, so it might be deleted (I'm still pretty new here myself)

(1) is fine, but it is a little odd because the verb is an infinitive... if you were just leaving, you would say "I am going to the north" or just "I am going north".  But your use of "where" is fine.  You could put a comma before "where" though.

(2) doesn't work - you want "which".  "Where" is for places, "which" is for things.  Also, "referred" needs a preposition somewhere.  We would say "This is the report which I referred to." - although, if we are being strict, prefer "This is the report to which I referred."

In the third, a problem is that when talking about the place where you are, you don't use "went" - you say "came" instead.  "This is the office.  I came to the office."  Although your summary is basically okay... It is actually tricky to choose how to summarize it.  I've got a moment to kill though:

> Q: Which office did you go to?
>
> A: *This* is the office that I went to.

This is acceptable, but only because the answerer is following the structure of the question.  Note the italics, for emphasis.  They make it more acceptable - the person answering is showing they know the construction is odd.

But it isn't just about following the structure of the question; we should note that "the office" is included in the answer.  When it is easy to shorten a sentence, but we do not, then a listener must consider if there is a reason we did not, and often there are multiple possibilities.  Emphasis on words can give clues in such cases.

Consider this slightly odd answer:

> Q: Which office did you go to?
>
> A: *This* is the office where I came.

We would have expected

> A: I came here.

But we're answering a question, so we don't need to have a complete sentence.  This might be more common:

> A: This office.

We can be more brief:

> A: This one.

And this doesn't follow the question as well, but saves a syllable, so we allow it:

> A: Here.

That's probably more information than you wanted, but I had fun.  Hope it helps somebody somehow.  Someone delete it if you want.

Comment: I appreciate your answer!